# Мониторинг устройств, по средством сравнения двух файлов на стороне сервера. В какую сторону копать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В какую сторону копать?
Хочу написать не большой скрипт мониторинга, который будет проверять значения из одного файла с другим.
И если значение будет совпадать будет писать работает, если не совпадает, пишет не работает.
Исходный файл это динамический файл на который лежит на сервере, в нём пишутся строки подключённых устройств, в этом файл порядка 200 строк:

```
101.5.0.24,AAAAAAAAAAAA,95.95.95.95:41921,Fri Jan  3 18:39:23 2020
101.5.0.25,BBBBBBBBBBBB,95.95.95.95:40962,Fri Jan  3 18:39:24 2020
101.5.0.23,CCCCCCCCCCCC,95.95.95.95:37829,Fri Jan  3 18:39:24 2020
101.5.0.22,DDDDDDDDDDDD,95.95.95.95:60791,Fri Jan  3 18:39:14 2020
```

В моём файле будут заготовлены все мак адреса:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDD
```

В конечном итоге, хочу что бы из моего файла сравнивались мак-адреса с исходным файлом на сервере, построчно, и если какого то мака не будет, будет соответствующий принт типа не работает и т.д.

Сейчас в голову приходит только реализация с заведением переменных под каждый мак и потом if - else, но это это очень долго и геморно.
Есть ли другие варианты? Натолкните на правильное решение.

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html

Answer (score 0):

Реализация будет зависеть от того, что вы конкретно хотите.
Файл с MAC адресами открываете и записываете все его строки в 1 set(). Он будет хранилищем нужных вам MAC адресов. 
Это даст возможность проверять вхождение с помощью оператора [in за O(1)](https://pythonz.net/references/named/slozhnost-operatsii-so-mnozhestvami/)
Добавление .add() и удаление .remove() так же работают за O(1)

Дальше обрабатываете ваши данные:

1. Открываете построчно
2. Из каждой строки через Регулярные выражения внимаете нужную вам информацию. Или если данные одинакового формата возможно вас устроит split(",").
3. Проверяете вхождение if split(",")[ 1 ] in set()