# Получить полный список мак-адресов из одного файл в другой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  3 23:49:14 2020
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
744D2805E1FB,95.95.95.95:36008,10914797,6045964,Thu Dec 26 19:55:51 2019
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
172.17.0.2,AAAAAAAAAAAA,95.95.95.95:36008,Fri Jan  3 23:48:35 2020
172.17.0.3,BBBBBBBBBBBB,95.95.95.95:36008,Fri Jan  3 23:48:35 2020
172.17.0.5,CCCCCCCCCCCC,95.95.95.95:36008,Fri Jan  3 23:48:35 2020
172.17.0.6,DDDDDDDDDDDD,95.95.95.95:36008,Fri Jan  3 23:48:35 2020
172.17.0.7,EEEEEEEEEEEE,95.95.95.95:36008,Fri Jan  3 23:48:35 2020
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

Из него надо выбрать все мак-адреса:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Делаю я это всё скриптом

```
sv = 0
sg = 0
file = open('4.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if line.find('GLOBAL') > -1:
        sg += 1
    if sv == 1 and sg == 0:
            info = {}
            info['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
            info['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]

            mac_log = info['mac']
            ip_log = ' IP: ' + info['ip']
            info = []
            filename = open('result.txt', 'w')
            filename.write(mac_log)

            print(mac_log + ' |' + ip_log)
    if line.find('Virtual Address,Common Name,') > -1:
        sv += 1

file.close()
```

Но в результате в записи конечного файла result.txt получаю всегда лишь только последний мак EEEEEEEEEEEE, а хотелось бы получать все.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мониторинг устройств, по средством сравнения двух файлов на стороне сервера. В какую сторону копать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065609/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%92-%d0%ba)

Comment: длинна фиксированная? eсли так то можно рeгуляркой

Comment: а, тю, так вы молодeц, вы файл опустошали каждый раз, нe мудрeнно..

Comment: А зачем это `info = []`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного переписал алгоритм:

- Файл `open('result.txt', 'a')` [открывается в режиме добавления данных](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), т.к. `w` предварительно очистит файл
- Оператор `with` сам закроет файлы, не нужно `close` вызывать
- Упростил работу с флагам, достаточно одного
- Упростил проверку строки. Метод `find` мне кажется меньше подходит
- В `.write(mac` добавил символ `'\n'` (перевод строки), иначе все записи будут в одну строку
- Убрал ненужное создание словаря

Пример:

```
with open('4.txt') as f_in, open('result.txt', 'a') as f_out:
    found = False

    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith('Virtual Address,Common Name,'):
            found = True
            continue

        if not found:
            continue

        if line.startswith('GLOBAL'):
            break

        ip = line.split(',')[0]
        mac = line.split(',')[1]

        ip_log = ' IP: ' + ip
        f_out.write(mac + '\n')

        print(mac + ' |' + ip_log)
```

В консоли:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA | IP: 172.17.0.2
BBBBBBBBBBBB | IP: 172.17.0.3
CCCCCCCCCCCC | IP: 172.17.0.5
DDDDDDDDDDDD | IP: 172.17.0.6
EEEEEEEEEEEE | IP: 172.17.0.7
```

В `result.txt`:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: всeгда думал, как читаeтся ваш ник?

Comment: @finally, что-то вроде `джил девять ред` :D

Comment: вы убили интригу(

Comment: @gil9red Друзья, всем спасибо, либо я дурак либо было очень поздно вчера)) Мне казалось, что я перебрал уже разные варианты и в том числе все комбинации записи - до записи файла. Всё оказалось предельно просто, действительно решилось переключением в режим до записи a.

Answer (score 1):

Pежим файла `w` (`open('result.txt', 'w')`) переписывает, все что было ранее, поэтому можно решить проблему открывая файл в режиме a, что не стирает предыдущие файлы, поэтому получается дозаписывание данных.

```
sv = 0
sg = 0
file = open('4.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if line.find('GLOBAL') > -1:
        sg += 1
    if sv == 1 and sg == 0:
            info = {}
            info['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
            info['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]

            mac_log = info['mac']
            ip_log = ' IP: ' + info['ip']
            info = []
            filename = open('result.txt', 'a')
            filename.write(mac_log)

            print(mac_log + ' |' + ip_log)
    if line.find('Virtual Address,Common Name,') > -1:
        sv += 1

file.close()
```

Либо

- Oткрывать файл в with
- Открывать 'result.txt' до цикла

Comment: Код это хорошо, но лучше добавьте причину проблемы, а именно в том, что режим файла `w` (`open('result.txt', 'w')`) переписывает, все что было ранее, поэтому можно решить проблему открывая файл в режиме `a`, что не стирает файл, поэтому получается дозаписывание данных. Либо еще посоветовать 1) открывать файл в `with` 2) Открывать `'result.txt'` до цикла

Comment: @gil9red Позаимствовал вашу формулировку :)

Answer (score 0):

как ужe замeтили вышe - ваша ошибка в **форматe открытия файла**, а имeнно:

`r` - чтeниe данных из файла.

`w` - запись в файл, всe данныe в файлe **удаляются**.

`a` - ДОзапись в файл, то eсть в конeц.

Comment: Так и есть) с (а) всё заработало так как надо) был невнимателен....